# How to update lightning datatable?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have the following code : -
js file

```
export default class ChildCmp extends LightningElement {
    lastId = 4;
    contacts = [
        { id: 0, Name: 'Aditya' },
        { id: 1, Name: 'Nitesh' },
        { id: 2, Name: 'Ankit' },
        { id: 3, Name: 'Samarth' },
        { id: 4, Name: 'Raghav' },
    ];
    data = this.contacts;
    columns = [
        { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name' }
    ];
    @api
    addContact(contact) {
        console.log(this.lastId, contact);
        this.contacts.push({ id: ++this.lastId, Name: contact });
        this.data = this.contacts;
        console.log(this.data);
    }
}
```

html file

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable
    key-field="id"
    data={data}
    columns={columns}>
</lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

whenever addContacts method is called from parent lightning-datatable must be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by:

```
@track contacts = [
```

This allows the LWC framework to detect changes (e.g. Array.push), or:

```
this.data = [...this.contacts];
```

This copies the array, which LWC will detect and automatically update the table, or:

```
this.contacts = [...this.contacts, { id: ++this.lastId, Name: contact }];
```

Which copies the old array, and adds the new element to the end.

You do not need to do all of the above, just choose one.

All of these methods have approximately the same performance characteristics, it's just a matter of making sure LWC can detect a change in the data.